# Show that $\alpha^n+\beta^n+\gamma^n=2^{2n+1}\,cos\,\frac{n\pi}{3}+\left(-\frac12\right)^n$

Tags: complex-numbers

$$z^n=r^n(\cos{n}\theta+i\sin{n}\theta)$$
$$\alpha=2+2\sqrt3\,i$$
$${\Rightarrow}\,(2+2\sqrt3\,i)^n=\left(\sqrt{2^2+(2\sqrt{3})^2}\right)^n\left(\cos\frac{n\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{n\pi}{3}\right)$$
$${\Rightarrow}\,\alpha^n=4^n\left(\cos\frac{n\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{n\pi}{3}\right)$$
$$\beta=2-2\sqrt3\,i$$
$${\Rightarrow}\,(2-2\sqrt3\,i)^n=\left(\sqrt{2^2+(2\sqrt{3})^2}\right)^n\left(\cos(-\frac{n\pi}{3})+i\sin(-\frac{n\pi}{3})\right)$$
$${\Rightarrow}\,\beta^n=4^n\left(\cos(-\frac{n\pi}{3})+i\sin(-\frac{n\pi}{3})\right)$$

$$\gamma=-\frac12$$
$${\Rightarrow}\,\gamma^n=\left(-\frac12\right)^n$$

$$\alpha^n+\beta^n+\gamma^n=$$
$$\left(4^n\left(\cos\frac{n\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{n\pi}{3}\right)\right)+\left(4^n\left(\cos(-\frac{n\pi}{3})+i\sin(-\frac{n\pi}{3})\right)\right)+\left(-\frac12\right)^n$$
What have I done wrong here? The Mark Scheme has $$\,\beta^n=4^n\left(\cos(\frac{n\pi}{3})-i\sin(\frac{n\pi}{3})\right)$$

Rewriting the equation with this in mind
$$\alpha^n+\beta^n+\gamma^n=$$
$$\left(4^n\left(\cos\frac{n\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{n\pi}{3}\right)\right)+\left(4^n\left(\cos(\frac{n\pi}{3})-i\sin(\frac{n\pi}{3})\right)\right)+\left(-\frac12\right)^n$$
$${\Rightarrow}\,2\left(4^{n}\cos\frac{n\pi}{3}\right)+\left(-\frac12\right)^n$$
$${\Rightarrow}\,2\left(2^{2n}\cos\frac{n\pi}{3}\right)+\left(-\frac12\right)^n$$
Now I'm stuck, where does the $^{n+1}$ come from? And what happens to the $2$?
$$2^{2n+1}\,cos\,\frac{n\pi}{3}+\left(-\frac12\right)^n$$

Comment: $2\cdot 2^{2n} = 2^{2n+1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the sine and cosine graphs you will see that:

$$cos{\theta}=cos(-\theta)$$
$$sin(-\theta)=-sin\theta$$
Therefore:
$$\beta^n=\left(4^n\left(\cos(-\frac{n\pi}{3})+i\sin(-\frac{n\pi}{3})\right)\right)=\left(4^n\left(\cos(\frac{n\pi}{3})-i\sin(\frac{n\pi}{3})\right)\right)$$
Using the exponent rule:
$$(x^m)(x^n)=x^{m+n}$$
$$2(2^{2n})=(2^1)(2^{2n})=2^{2n+1}$$